# Avoiding global of Facebook javascript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

As we can see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Loading the SDK adds a global FB object. I am building a lib which i want to have a 'MYLIB.Facebook' namespace containing a loader of the JDK which adds the FB object as property  of that namespace when loaded.

Thnx in advance.